# Is there a method/property/var to get a list of skipped tests in python3 unittest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a few test cases that are in `unittest.Testcase` class. I skip a couple of them. At the end of the run, can I get a list of those skipped tests?

Comment: i think `pytest` may do this but i have not used `pytest` so i can not write an answer on speculation.

Answer (score 2):

All skipped tests are stored as name-reason tuples in the `skipped` list in the `result` attribute of the `TestProgram` object that `unittest.main()` returns:

```
import unittest
import sys

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @unittest.skip("I don't want to do it")
    def test_nothing(self):
        self.fail("shouldn't happen")

    def test_something(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

test = unittest.main(exit=False) # do not exit after testing is done
sys.stdout.flush() # flush stdout so that the following output will be at the end
for name, reason in test.result.skipped:
    print(name, reason)
```

This outputs:

```
s.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK (skipped=1)
test_nothing (__main__.MyTestCase) I don't want to do it
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the tests at the command line, say, as:

`python3 -m unittest`

then you can use the `-v` verbose option to list the result of each test, and look for the skipped ones.

`python3 -m unittest -v`

If the list is long, you can just `grep` for 'skipped' in the output. E.g.

`python3 -m unittest -v | grep skipped`